# Drag to adjust size of two divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a browserify module I've made for resizing two divs I have beside each other. The idea is that I have two panes with a bar between them which I can grab and drag to resize the panes. As one pane gets bigger the other gets smaller. It's not really that important for the code review that this is a browserify module, if you're not familiar with it, you can just focus at the Javascript in the module.

Feedback on the code, especially the Javascript module, is greatly appreciated. Also, feel free to nitpick as long as you specify when you're doing so.

```
;(function () {
    const $ = require("jquery");

    module.exports = function (dragbarElementId, leftElementPaneId, rightElementPaneId, paneContainerElementId) {
        const $paneContainer = $(`#${paneContainerElementId}`);
        const $dragbar = $(`#${paneContainerElementId} #${dragbarElementId}`);
        const $leftPane = $(`#${paneContainerElementId} #${leftElementPaneId}`);
        const $rightPane = $(`#${paneContainerElementId} #${rightElementPaneId}`);

        let dragging = false;

        // Todo: Load these from previous session.
        let leftPanePercentage = 50;
        let rightPanePercentage = 50;

        function setInitialPaneSizes() {
            if ($leftPane && $rightPane) {
                const unit = $paneContainer.width() / (leftPanePercentage + rightPanePercentage);
                $leftPane.width(unit * leftPanePercentage);
                $rightPane.width(unit * rightPanePercentage);
            }
        }

        $(document).on("ready", setInitialPaneSizes);
        $(window).on("resize", setInitialPaneSizes);

        if ($dragbar) {
            $dragbar.on("mousedown", (mousedownEvent) => {
                mousedownEvent.preventDefault();
                dragging = true;
                let prevPageX = mousedownEvent.pageX;

                $(document).on("mousemove", (mousemoveEvent) => {
                    if (dragging) {
                        if ($leftPane && $rightPane) {
                            const deltaPageX = mousemoveEvent.pageX - prevPageX;
                            prevPageX = mousemoveEvent.pageX;
                            $leftPane.width($leftPane.width() + deltaPageX);
                            $rightPane.width($rightPane.width() - deltaPageX);
                            leftPanePercentage = 100 / $paneContainer.width() * $leftPane.width();
                            rightPanePercentage = 100 / $paneContainer.width() * $rightPane.width();
                        }
                    }
                });

                $(document).on("mouseup", () => {
                    if (dragging) {
                        dragging = false;
                        $(document).unbind("mousemove");
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
}());
```

I have adapted the code to work on JSFiddle, so you can now try a working version [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xmw5kpgc/5/).

Comment: Can you fix up the code snippet. There is an error whilst running the code snippet.

Comment: As I said in the OP, it's a browserify module, so the code snippets aren't supposed to work right out of the box. I can try to adapt it so it'll run in a normal JavaScript environment if that helps with the reviewing.